# Extract Few Values with Beautiful Soup

Tags: tags, beautifulsoup

```
 <p class="">
    Teacher:
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_0"
>Scott</a>
             <span class="ghost">|</span> 
    Students:
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_1"
>Benedict</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_2"
>Chiwetel</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_3"
>Rachel</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_4"
>Benedict Wong</a>
    </p>
```

I would like to extract teacher's name - "Scott" which is under the tag of "Teacher" and extract all students' name under the tag of "Students". I tried:
`soup.find(lambda tag:tag)` and it returned

```
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_0"
>Scott</a>
```

I think it is not a right approach. How the code should actually be to extract both the names under "teacher" and "students" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your HTML block won't change much when parsing other pages you can find your `p` tag by class ( Your example has none ) and verify if the `Teacher` text is present.

If it is get the `.contents[1]` from the p tag which is the first `a` on the element.

Next find all `a` tags on which the `href` attribute doesn't match your teachers.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """<p class="">
Teacher:
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_0"
>Scott</a>
         <span class="ghost">|</span> 
Students:
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_1"
>Benedict</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_2"
>Chiwetel</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_3"
>Rachel</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm12345/?ref_=adv_4"
>Benedict Wong</a>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "html.parser")

Classroom = soup.find(lambda x: "Teacher" in x.get_text())

if Classroom is not None:

    Teacher = Classroom.contents[1]
    TeacherUrl = Teacher["href"]

    Students = Classroom.find_all(lambda tag: tag.has_attr('href') and TeacherUrl not in tag["href"])

    print (Teacher.text)
    for Student in Students:
        print (Student.text)
```

Which outputs:

> Scott
>
> Benedict
>
> Chiwetel
>
> Rachel
>
> Benedict Wong